# ReExecute AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, code-reuse, cancel-button

I have several `AsyncTask` in my Project to grab data from some given apis.
I followed the following steps.

```
1) execute an Async Task and try to grab datas from there.
2) check conditions for internet and server down
3) if any issue in api or internet or server then show dialog [custom from self made class]
4) dismiss button for canceling the dialog and go back to the working stage of `app may be even by closing the activity`
```

My problem is I want to keep a `Button` **"Retry"** such that it shall be re executing the `AsyncTask`.
I searched of passing `AsyncTask` but it seemed worthless as I concluded `AsyncTask` cannot be passed. And so I am forced to repeat same code `cancel(true)` for various times

It would be very useful if anyone could give me solution for it with this code re-use concept.

Comment: What's wrong with creating and executing the AsyncTask from a function and then call it from your `DialogListener`?

Comment: How to create various Async Task from a single function with various context to run on? Any simple example would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved The problem by using a retry button that creates the new object of class implementing Async-task and executing that new object.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "retry" the same AsyncTask object - you can only call AsyncTask#execute() once. However, you could create a new AsyncTask instance when the user decides to retry the download task.

Comment: yes I want to create Async Task instance when pressing the Retryu Button. But How to do that?

Comment: Try putting your original AsyncTask code in a function, and call it whenever the Button is pressed. Make sure you cancel any previous tasks before doing this.

Comment: I have various async tasks, how would I know the specific one? And I have to do this for each.